# MSSQL how to select string from the right of the third delimiter (counting from the right)

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

So my question is as follows:-
I have multiple strings with variable amounts of delimiters, the text between the delimiters can also vary in number:-

```
fug\klde\hzt\jkljlkjlkjl\hgftb\jghgf\ooorr\ter\fdgd
wegf\df\jght\kfd\dfgert
```

What I need to do is to cut the string and leave only the following from the examples:-

```
ooorr\ter\fdgd
jght\kfd\dfgert
```

so basically the third delimiter from the right side.
I have been able to use RIGHT, CHARINDEX and REVERSE to give me the last part of the string(s) but I am struggling for the rest.
Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Text processing is something you might require to do in presentation layer but naive way is to do like below:

```
Select Substring(col1, len(col1) - CharIndex('\', reverse(col1), Charindex('\',reverse(col1),charindex('\', reverse(col1),1)+1)+1)+2, len(col1)) from #delimiterdata
```

Output as below:

```
+-----------------+
|     Output      |
+-----------------+
| ooorr\ter\fdgd  |
| jght\kfd\dfgert |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with a little XML in concert with a a Cross Apply

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'fug\klde\hzt\jkljlkjlkjl\hgftb\jghgf\ooorr\ter\fdgd')
,(2,'wegf\df\jght\kfd\dfgert')
,(3,'kfd\dfgert')               

Select A.ID
      ,NewValue = reverse(Concat(Pos1,'\'+Pos2,'\'+Pos3))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(reverse(A.SomeCol),'\','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) n) X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewValue
1   ooorr\ter\fdgd
2   jght\kfd\dfgert
3   kfd\dfgert      --<<Note: Doesn't have 3 but will produce the last two
```

Comment: While these are all really good solutions, I found that the answer from John Cappelletti was, for me the best as it is easy to add or reduce the amount of delimiters. Many Many Thanks!!

Comment: @CraigRobinson Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) you could do this:

```
-- sample data
declare @yourtable table (someId int identity, someString varchar(1000));
insert @yourtable 
values ('fug\klde\hzt\jkljlkjlkjl\hgftb\jghgf\ooorr\ter\fdgd'),('wegf\df\jght\kfd\dfgert');

with stringPrep AS 
(
  select 
    someId, 
    someString, 
    dPos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by t.someid order by ng.position desc),
    position
  from @yourtable t
  cross apply dbo.NGrams8k(t.someString, 1) ng
  where token = '\'
)
select
  someId, 
  someString, 
  newString = substring(someString, position+1, 1000)
from stringPrep
where dpos = 3;
```

Results

```
someId  someString                                                   newString
------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -----------------
1       fug\klde\hzt\jkljlkjlkjl\hgftb\jghgf\ooorr\ter\fdgd          ooorr\ter\fdgd
2       wegf\df\jght\kfd\dfgert                                      jght\kfd\dfgert
```